# Explode a column to execute an SQL search query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to perform a query based on a "contacts" table with a column "partners". I've stocked partner like this :

```
ID  Name     Partners
1 - Dupont - 3;8;14;11 
2 - Duporc - 2;3;8;11 
3 - Trobo - 1;2;5;8
```

I would like to permform a SQL query in order to retrieve all the contact who belongs to partner 2 for exemple. How can I explode "partners" column in order to do that with SQL ?

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE ... LIKE 2 ...??
```

Comment: DO NOT "stock" partners like this

Comment: You should be using a junction table, say `ContactPartners`, with one row per contact and partner.

Comment: Thank for the structure upgrade but I can't do that right now. I've to deal with this imposed structure. Is there any SQL function to split or explode this partners column ?

Comment: You could explode on the semicolon, then implode with a comma and use a `WHERE col IN()` clause in your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `REGEXP`

You can use regular expressions to check for the given number from the string.

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE Partners REGEXP '[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]'
```

another method is you can replace semicolon in select query and then use find in set

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2,REPLACE(Partners,";",","));
```

Comment: ...and also it may be `WHERE LOCATE(CONCAT(";", 2, ";"), CONCAT(";", Partners, ";"))` that should be faster then `REGEXP` but may be slower then `FIND_IN_SET`

Comment: SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE Partners REGEXP '[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]'
is way faster than the other solutions. Thank you guys !

Answer (score 1):

you can use FIND_IN_SET function ...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(3, Partners);

               OR

SELECT * FROM table
WHERE CONCAT(';', Partners, ';') LIKE '%,3,%'
```

I hop it's useful ...

Comment: please check this URL :- http://makitweb.com/search-value-within-comma-separated-values-mysql/

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` is used for comma seperated values and here the problem is values are semicolon seperated